# PlatformNotSupportedException: System.Data.OleDb is not supported on this platform

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, package.json

I am still trying to upload excel file into my SQL workbench DB and the code i did write to import those file works and it actually imports the excel files and saves it into the folder i specified . But however when i check my DB there's nothing in it and as well as i also get the error i mentioned above. Any advice or recommendation will be of great help . Below are my codes. Thanks.

Model Data class is here

namespace air_traffic_weather.Models
{
public class Data
{
[Key]

```
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Ident { get; set; }

    public string type { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public int latitude_deg { get; set; }

    public int longitude_deg { get; set; }

    public int elevation_ft { get; set; }

    public string continent { get; set; }

    public string iso_country { get; set; }

    public string iso_region { get; set; }
    public string municipality { get; set; }

    public string schedule_service { get; set; }

    public string gps_code { get; set; }

    public string iata_code { get; set; }

    public string local_code { get; set; }

    public string home_link { get; set; }

    public string wikipedia_link { get; set; }

    public string keywords { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public DateTime Updated { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

}

Home Controller

```
    [HttpPost("Index")]
    public IActionResult Index(IFormFile file)
    {


        if (file != null)
        {

            // giving the path where imma store my file that will be uploaded and they will be stored in a folder in made in the Root Path.

            string thePath = Path.Combine(this._hostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "ExcelData");

            // now checking to see if that directory already exists, if it does we don't get but if it ain't then we create one

            if (!Directory.Exists(thePath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(thePath);
            }

            // now it is time to save the excel file that we gonna upload yeah!!

            string theFileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            string theFilePath = Path.Combine(thePath, theFileName);

            using (FileStream theStream = new FileStream(theFilePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                file.CopyTo(theStream);
            }


            // let's also read the connection string for the excel file.

            string conString = "@Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties= 'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'";
            DataTable thedataTable = new DataTable();
            conString = string.Format(conString, theFilePath);

            OleDbConnection connectToExcel = new OleDbConnection(conString);
            OleDbCommand commandExcel = new OleDbCommand();
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            commandExcel.Connection = connectToExcel;
            // get the first excel sheet name
            connectToExcel.Open();
            DataTable dtExcelSchema;
            dtExcelSchema = connectToExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            string sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            connectToExcel.Close();
            // read data from first sheet
            connectToExcel.Open();
            commandExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]";
            adapter.SelectCommand = commandExcel;
            adapter.Fill(thedataTable);
            connectToExcel.Close();

            conString = this._configuration.GetConnectionString("cs");
            using (SqlConnection connectionToSql = new SqlConnection(conString))
            {
                using (SqlBulkCopy hugeCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionToSql))
                {

                    // here i will set my DB table name

                    hugeCopy.DestinationTableName = "Datas";

                    // HERE IMMA GO AHEAD AND THE EXCEL COLUMNS WITH THAT OF MY DB 

                    hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Id", "Id");
                    hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Ident", "Ident");
                    hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("type", "type");
                    hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("name", "name");
                    hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("latitude_degrees", "latitude_degrees");
                    hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("longitude_degrees", "longitude_degrees");
                    hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("elevation_feet", "elevation_feet");
                    hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("continent", "continent");
                    hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("iso_region", "iso_region");
                    hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("municipality", "municipality");
                    hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("schedule_service", "schedule_service");
                    hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("gps_code", "gps_code");
                    hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("iata_code", "iata_code");
                    hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("local_code", "local_code");
                    hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("home_link", "home_link");
                    hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("wikipedia_link", "wikipedia_link");
                    hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("keywords", "keywords");

                    connectionToSql.Open();
                    hugeCopy.WriteToServer(thedataTable);
                    connectionToSql.Close();



                }
            }
```

csproj file below

<PackageRefrence Include="System.Data.OleDb" Version="5.0.0-preview.8.20407.11 />

Comment: Are you using .NET Core or framework?

Comment: hey @GlynnHurrell, thanks for reaching out and i am using the framework

Comment: hmmm, did you install System.Data.OleDb via NuGet? - If so then try rolling back to a previous version

Comment: yes i did install that, but imma go ahead and reinstall an old version of the System.Data.OleDb and see what happens

Comment: You should be able to do it from the 'Manage Nuget Packages' - select the version on the right hand side.... choose the latest non-preview version (most likely 4.8)

Comment: okay got it, let do that straight away

Comment: this is latest version 4 package nuget does have :- dotnet add package System.Data.OleDb --version 4.7.1. So thats what i will try and install

Comment: dotnet.exe is for .NET Core, not .NET framework.... you should be using NuGet.exe for framework. Are u not using Visual Studio?

Comment: i am using visual studio

Comment: You should use the [NuGet package manager in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio) then

Comment: Also, you should able to reference System.Data.OleDb without installing a NuGet package. Right click the project, goto 'Add Reference' and find it in the list

Comment: hey @GlynnHurrell, i do really apologize for the misinformation but i am actually using .NET Core, i am not using the framework.

Comment: i tried installing it the nuget package  through my terminal but i got an error because i am using .NET Core but not the framework. Any advice will or suggestion will be of great help, thanks again

Comment: Ok well the answer then is that System.Data.Oledb isn't supported in .NET Core

Comment: I've added an answer

Comment: Okay great and thanks. i will go ahead and follow up that tutorial

Answer (score 3):

If You have installed Nuget Package, then try downgrading version.

I tried downgrading from v7.0 to v6.0 and it worked for me !!

Comment: .NET Core 3.1 does not support System.Data.OleDb v.7 it is need v.6

Answer (score 2):

**System.Data.OleDb is not supported in .NET Core**

In order to read from an Excel file you'll have to look at using a .NET library such as [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/).

There are plenty of tutorials such as [this one](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/12/09/reading-excel-files-in-net-core/)

Or you can change your project to target .NET Framework

Comment: EPPlus has changed its license recently and it seems that commercial use is no longer free

Comment: You can still use EPPlus 4 for free @Elnur (I know this is an old comment, but might help the next guy)